# Assign a tag programatically for stock status when product is saved in WooCommerce backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product, stock

I have created 3 tags 1.

- Backorder (id 111)
- In stock (id 112),
- Out of stock (id 113)

I would like these tags to be auto-assigned based on availability.

If I am able to get this working, I'll be using the `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object`, `woocommerce_product_quick_edit_save`, `woocommerce_product_set_stock`, `woocommerce_variation_set_stock` to capture the possible scenarios for stock status changes.

Below is what I have tried but it gives me a fatal error. If I do not use the if condition, then the tags get assigned but it does not meet my objective. Any advice?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'mycode_woocommerce_backorder_tag', 10, 2 );
function mycode_woocommerce_backorder_tag ($wc_get_product, $product) {
    if ($product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder(1)) {
        $wc_get_product->set_tag_ids(array(111));
        $wc_get_product->save();
        //wp_set_object_terms ($post_id, 'onbackorder', 'product_tag');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` hook has only 1 argument, which is `$product`

`$product->save();` is also not necessary, because this happens automatically

Copied from admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php

```php
/**
 * Set props before save.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', $product );

$product->save();
```

---

So to answer your question, you get:

```php
// When product is saved in WooCommerce backend
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    // managing_stock() - returns whether or not the product is stock managed.
    // on_backorder() – check if a product is on backorder.
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
        // Product set tag ids
        $product->set_tag_ids( array( 111 ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r. I have updated the question with the revised code. There is no error but the tags do not apply correctly sometimes may be due to a nesting issue in my code.

Comment: @Yo93sh Please do not edit existing questions that already contain an answer with new issues. “If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.”