# Need to save product twice to have auto tag updated correctly

Tags: if-statement, woocommerce, switch-statement, product, stock

Thanks to 7uc1f3r, I was able to programatically assign tags to products based on their stock status. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090406/assign-a-tag-programatically-for-stock-status-when-product-is-saved-in-woocommer)

However, I have run into an issue. There is no error. At times, I have to save the product twice for the correct tag to reflect. I have tried the code using `else` & `elseif` but the issue persists. If someone could guide me to use `switch` `case`, I can try that & see if the tags get assigned correctly on the first save. Alternatively, if there is information on why this would occur & possible remedies, please let me know. Looks like the product is in the process of saving in the backend & the tag gets assigned prior to that but I don't know for sure. Please advise.

[image]

```js
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'mycode_woocommerce_stockstatus_tag', 10, 1 );
function mycode_woocommerce_stockstatus_tag( $product ) {
    if( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (113) );
    }
    elseif( $product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (111) );
    }
    elseif( $product->is_in_stock() && !$product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (112) );
    }
}
```

I am also posting a variant of the code where I split out where stock is being managed or not. The if statements here are independent & appear to do a better job. However, I still request if someone could pitch in & help with `switch` `case` as I believe it will execute faster.

```js
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'mycode_woocommerce_stockstatus_tag', 10, 1 );
function mycode_woocommerce_stockstatus_tag( $product ) {
    if( $product->managing_stock() && ( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 ) ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (112) );
    }
    if( $product->managing_stock() && ( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) && ( $product->backorders_allowed() || $product->backorders_require_notification() ) ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (111) );
    }
    if( $product->managing_stock() && ( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) && !$product->backorders_allowed() && !$product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (113) );
    }
    if( !$product->managing_stock() && $product->is_in_stock() && !$product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (112) );
    }
    if( !$product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (111) );
    }
    if( !$product->managing_stock() && !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $product->set_tag_ids( array (113) );
    }
}
```